# find the number of ring homomorphism ?.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Given  $f : \mathbb {Z}_{4}  \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{10} $. find the number of ring homomorphism ?

My attempt :  I got $4$ , my thinking is that the idempotents element in $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ are $ \{ 0,1,5,6\}$, so there are $4$ ring homomorphism

Is its true ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is cyclic, everything is determined by $f(1)$.  Furthermore, you must have ord$(f(1)) \mid \mathbb{Z}_{10}$ by Lagrange's Theorem, so ord$(f(1)) \in \{1,2,5,10\}$.  Now obviously it can't be $5$ or $10$.  (Why?)  Now show the other two work, giving 2 homomorphisms.

Comment: can u more elaborate  more  i understantd 70 %

Comment: @jasmine  Sure, on what part?

Comment: @Dzook  how  it can not be  5 and 10 ?

Comment: @jasmine  If the order were 5, that means that $f(1), 2f(1), 3f(1), 4f(1),$ and $5f(1)=0$ are all distinct.  But, since $f$ is a homomorphism, $2f(1)=f(1)+f(1)=f(2)$, $3f(1)=f(3)$, $4f(1)=f(4)=f(0)=0$ and $5f(1)=f(5)=f(4+1)=f(0+1)=f(1)$, contradicting the fact that $5f(1) \neq f(1)$.  Basically, there are only 4 things in the domain, so there can't be more than that in the range.

Comment: ..@Dzooks thanks u  now  i understand 100%