# Is there any general formula for ring homomorphism if gcd$(p, q) \neq 1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is there  any general formula  for  ring homomorphism  from  $\mathbb{Z}_{n}  \rightarrow  \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$   if gcd$(p, q)  \neq 1$ ?

I  got the link :[What are all the homomorphisms between the rings $\mathbb{Z}_{18}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{15}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303/what-are-all-the-homomorphisms-between-the-rings-mathbbz-18-and-mathbb)

But I am finding it difficult to show    that gcd$(p, q)  \neq 1$ ?

Any any hints/solution ?

Comment: Do ring homomorphisms send $1$ to $(1,1)$?

Comment: @Ihf   im not getting

Comment: @jasmine If a ring homomorphism is either surjective or if it is nontrivial and between integral domains, it necessarily sends unity to unity - knowing this can be useful in figuring out more about the nature of the homomorphism. But if both the aforementioned conditions fail, then it may send the unity to something else (the most obvious example is the trivial homomorphism into a non trivial ring) (there may be other conditions besides the ones mentioned - those are just some examples that crop up frequently)

Comment: Why is it difficult to see that $gcd(p,q)\neq 1$? You have already asked a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327131/find-the-number-of-ring-homomorphism).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* A ring homomorphism must send $1$ to an idempotent.

Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z}_{n}  \to  \mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$ be a ring homomorphism. Let $\phi([1]_n)=e=(a,b)$. Then the additivity of $\phi$ implies $\phi([x]_n)=xe$. In particular, $ne=0$. When this is satisfied, the map  $\phi([x]_n)=xe$ is well defined.
The multiplicativity of $\phi$ implies $e^2=e$. So, $\phi$ is determined by the choice of $e$, which must have additive order dividing $n$ and be idempotent.

If you require that a ring homomorphism preserve units, then $e=(1,1)$ and the additive requirement $ne=0$ is the only one. Otherwise, you need to consider the idempotents in $\mathbb{Z}_{p} \times \mathbb{Z}_{q}$.